# Microsoft SQL Server "OPENDATASOURCE" Unicode Arabic

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, t-sql

I'm trying to read CSV file from SQL Server using this query

```
SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                             'Text;Database=C:\xxx\;HDR=YES')...[export#csv]
```

it's working well
my issue here is the Unicode the file is using UTF-8 encoding
how to define the Unicode in OPENDATASOURCE

the file that I'm reading is not showing the Arabic character in correct encoding

[image: Wrong encoding]

Comment: what if you use `OleDbConnection, OleDbDataReader` etc?

Comment: `Extended Properties=\"Text;CharacterSet=UTF8...`

Comment: I tried this 
SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Text;Database=C:\ODKBriefcase\ExportedData\28\;HDR=YES; Extended Properties = "CharacterSet=UTF8"')...[export#csv]

but I got this error

Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: SQL Server only introducted UTF-8 support in SQL Server 2019; if you're using a prior version you'll want to change the encode of the file before you before the ETL process.

Comment: the file is UTF8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one worked for me

```
SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Text;Database=C:\xxx\;HDR=YES
;Extended Properties="text;characterset=65001;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"')...[export#csv]
```